# Getting a Node values from XML document

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

my Code looks something like this, I want to print the value of the currency but i donot know where i am wrong

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("filepath");
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//gesmes/gesmes");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   Console.WriteLine(node["currency"]);
}
```

### My Xml document looks like this

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
    xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
  <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
  <gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
  </gesmes:Sender>
  <Cube>
    <Cube time="2014-07-21">
      <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3518"/>
      <Cube currency="JPY" rate="136.97"/>
      <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
    </Cube>
  </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Comment: have you had a change to review my answer? if it helped you please consider marking it as **accepted answer**

Answer (score 4):

there are multiple things wrong with your code:

## Namespaces

you have to add a namespace manager and add the namespaces defined in your xml

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("lo", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
```

notice how I added the default namespace with the `lo` alias to be able to query it using XPath later on

## XPath

what are you trying to select?
`gesmes` is a namespace in your document not a node you can select. From your question I guess you want to select Cubes containing the currency attribute like so:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//lo:Cube[@currency]", nsmgr);
```

notice that you need to include the namespace manager

## Value

the value you are looking for is not a `Node Value` like

```
<Cube currency="USD">1.3518</Cube>
```

would be but an attribute value
select it using

```
node.Attributes["currency"].Value;
```

## put together

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("filepath");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("lo", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//lo:Cube[@currency]", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["rate"].Value);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```